# How to play Brightcove RTMP URLs on JWPlayer?

Tags: video, jwplayer, rtmp, brightcove, jwplayer6

I am trying to implement the dynamic RTMP streaming supported by [JWPplayer](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430398-dynamic-rtmp-streaming) and [Brightcove](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/using-multi-bitrate-streaming).

I'm currently using the [find_video_by_id](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/samples/find_video_by_id.html) method to get a JSON package with the available RTMP streams, you can get an example by selecting the renditions field in [this sample](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/samples/find_video_by_id.html). Basically any of the URLs will look like the one bellow but won't reproduce in the player (I am testing with JWPlayer and VLC).

```
rtmp://brightcove.fcod.llnwd.net/a500/e1/uds/rtmp/ondemand/&mp4:1937897674001/1937897674001_2790025682001_Sea-Crab.mp4&1415984400000&ed8715a655417a4c5d8db202bc3cb926
```

The MP4 URL for the same rendition however, can be played without issues.

```
http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/uds/pd/1937897674001/1937897674001_2790025641001_Sea-Crab.mp4
```

I have read [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/670758?tstart=0) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249558/rtmp-stream-from-brightcove) that this might be due to access restrictions but it doesn't make sense that Brightcove would provide the RTMP URLs if they can't be used. Also the videos are owned, uploaded and consumed by us and we are using the API keys provided by BC to fetch them.

Comment: I am fairly certain that Brightcove's RTMP URLs have tokens set, so they will expire.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying. By using Brigthcove's API I should be getting the current RTMP URL, even if it expires later, it should be valid at the time it is requested.

Comment: The error I get says cannot connect to server. Is it possible that BrightCove has locked down their RTMP streams to be played only through their Flash player?

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing. Already contacted Brightcove's support, I will update the question as soon as I have additional info.

Comment: Well, support says only BC's player can consume their RTMP streams. If you ask me, it makes no sense that the default delivery method of their public API is RTMP if you can't use them. I'm still waiting on the final answer but I don't think it will be any different.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer It's final. Only BC's player can consume the RTMP streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only Brightcove's player can consume the RTMP streams**.

From Brightcove's support team:

> Unfortunately it just isn't possible to use the RTMP stream outside the player.  You can use the http mp4 that is available to use.  But with the security measures attached to the RTMP stream they can't be used outside of the Brightcove player.

From [Brightcove's Site](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/content-delivery-options#fms):

> Brightcove has enhanced RTMP delivery by employing a time-to-live (TTL) token for each video file delivered in a Video Cloud player. Time to live (sometimes abbreviated TTL) is a limit on the period of time or number of iterations or transmissions in computer and computer network technology that a unit of data (for example, a packet) can experience before it should be discarded. Through Flash Media Server, Brightcove has implemented a customized approach that provides additional security into the Flash Media Server (FMS) server infrastructure on the CDN. This was accomplished using a hashing algorithm and a Time To Live (TTL) for each stream.