# JWPlayer: Dynamic bit rate switching with MP4 files?

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, jwplayer6

We are currently using [Brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com/) to host our videos. We wanted to take advantage of the RTMP streams available for dynamic bit rate switching but [unfortunately they are only available to BC's own player](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27025776/1132838).

Assuming [HTTP pseudo streaming](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430518-pseudo-streaming-in-flash) is available, is there a way to achieve dynamic bit rate switching with MP4 files?

I could only find examples for [RTMP streaming](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430398-dynamic-rtmp-streaming) and [manual rendition toggling](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428524-hd-quality-toggling) in the sopport pages.

---

**Edit:**

This will allow multiple video renditions, but won't dynamically adjust to the user's available bandwith. Also, the default rendition has to be manually selected.

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
      sources: [{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo720mp4",
        label: "720p HD"
      },{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo360.mp4",
        label: "360p SD",
        "default": "true"
      },{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo180mp4",
        label: "180p Web"
      }]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: HTTP delivered MP4 files can't be dynamically switched. You would have to use HLS.

Comment: I guess research never ends :-). I will look into BC's HLS possibilities.

Comment: Is it possible to get JWPlayer to automatically select the best rendition for the user's bandwidth using the sources approach?

Comment: Not for HTTP Served MP4 files, I'm afraid.